# nested if else statement in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm interested in learning javascript for fun.  I've only been studying for about a couple of weeks so far and I'm trying to solve a coding exercise but I'm having a hard time doing it.  Below is my code and I keep getting an error that states I'm missing a ( before a condition.  I've looked it over several times and don't see where I'm missing the (.  Thanks guys.

```
var numbers = 0;
for (numbers = 0; numbers < 101; numbers++) {
  if (numbers % 3 === 0 && numbers != 0)
    if (numbers % 5 === 0)
      document.write("fizzbuzz <br>");
    else {
      document.write("fizz <br>");
    }
  if
  else(numbers % 5 === 0 && numbers != 0) {
    document.write("buzz <br>");
  }
  else {
    document.write("This is the number " + numbers + " in the 10 base number      scale. <br>");
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a really good idea to get into the habit of being really consistent about indentation and use of `{ ... }` blocks after `for` and `if` blocks. Otherwise, it's easy to get confused about which `else` go with which `if`.

Comment: I went back and added the indentations where it was needed and it looks so much more legible.   It definitely makes correcting errors easier.  Thanks guys.

Comment: If an answer helped, please mark it as correct so others who see will know what worked for you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if else` is what you have.

`else if` is what it should be.

So because you put the `if` before else, it's expecting a `(`. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though its perfectly fine to use `if-else` without `{}` for single line statements, it usually creates problem than saving some characters. Its always preferred to use the `{}` to avoid confusion even though for single line statements. Also you have interchanged `else if` with an `if else` before the check for `number%5`. You can change your code to below

```js
var numbers = 0;

for(numbers = 0; numbers < 101; numbers++){
  if(numbers%3===0 && numbers !=0) {
    if(numbers%5===0) {
      document.write("fizzbuzz <br>");
    } else{
      document.write("fizz <br>");
    } 
  } else if (numbers%5===0 && numbers !=0){
    document.write("buzz <br>");
  } else{
    document.write("This is the number " + numbers + " in the 10 base number      scale. <br>");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **if** is written before **else** when it should be the opposite, see the "<-------------- HERE"-mark.

```
var numbers = 0;
for (numbers = 0; numbers < 101; numbers++) {
  if (numbers % 3 === 0 && numbers != 0)
    if (numbers % 5 === 0)
      document.write("fizzbuzz <br>");
    else {
      document.write("fizz <br>");
    }
  if <-------------- HERE
  else(numbers % 5 === 0 && numbers != 0) {
    document.write("buzz <br>");
  }
  else {
    document.write("This is the number " + numbers + " in the 10 base number      scale. <br>");
  }
}
```

It should be:

```
else if (numbers % 5 === 0 && numbers != 0)
{
    document.write("buzz <br>");
}
```